# Cypher request to get actors who played in most movies, order by count

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to follow a video tutorial about neo4j that uses the Movies graph database found by default in neo4j.

In this tutorial there is an assignment asking to **retrieve actors who played in most of the movies, ordering by count DESC and limit to 5.**

The tutorial solution doesn't match with my result and there is something I don't understand. My result get duplicates movies while I'm using a similar Cypher request.

Tutorial solution:

> MATCH (actor:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]-() RETURN actor.name,
>                                    COUNT(*) as COUNT ORDER BY COUNT DESC LIMIT 5;

[image]

In my solution I get duplicates:

> MATCH (actor:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]-(movie:Movie) RETURN actor.name,
>                                   COLLECT(movie.title), COUNT(*) as COUNT ORDER BY COUNT DESC LIMIT 5;
>   [image]
>
> "Meg Ryan"    [**"Top Gun",** "You've Got Mail", "Sleepless in Seattle", "Joe Versus the Volcano", "When Harry Met Sally", "Top Gun", "You've Got Mail", "Sleepless in Seattle", "Joe Versus the Volcano", "When Harry Met Sally", **"Top Gun"**, "You've Got Mail", "Sleepless in Seattle", "Joe Versus the Volcano", "When Harry Met Sally"]

When I use :

> MATCH (actor:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]-(movie:Movie) RETURN actor.name,
>                                   **COLLECT(DISTINCT movie.title)**, COUNT(*) as COUNT ORDER BY COUNT DESC LIMIT 5;

I got the same movies as the tutorials solutions but the COUNT column is still showing a duplicate movies COUNT.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with the Tutorial - it is very easy to add the same nodes multiple times with Cypher CREATE statements. Maybe this has happened to you too?

Maybe just run:

MATCH(n) return n;

and then eyeball the whole graph - the tutorial should be small enough to do this & you'll see if you have duplicates.

Comment: Hi Sinister. I didn't add any CREATE Statements...I even restarted a fresh sessio of the neo4j juste to make sure. I get the same results as the tutorial only when I use COUNT(DISTINCT movie.title), while the tutorial doesn't use any DISTINCT  statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `distinct` inside `count`:

```
MATCH (actor:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]-(movie:Movie) 
RETURN 
    actor.name,
    COLLECT(DISTINCT movie.title), 
    COUNT(DISTINCT movie) as COUNT 
ORDER BY COUNT DESC LIMIT 5;
```

P.S. In this case result of `COUNT(*)` is count of patterns.